# If the quarks in a neutron are (up,down,down), why isn't it negatively charged?

Tags: standard-model, charge, quarks, baryons

If the quarks in a neutron are (up,down,down), why isn't it negatively charged? Excuse the silly question, just wondering.

Comment: Because the quarks have fractional charges that cancel.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that while its net charge is zero, the neutron has a non-null charge distribution, something like [this](http://perso.ya.com/sardin1/news13.htm).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The up quark has a charge of $+2/3$, the down has a charge of $-1/3$.
If you have a bound state of charged particles, the total charge is just the charge of the elementary constituents.
The neutron consists of one up quark and two down quarks, so the total charge $Q$ is:

$$Q = 2/3 + 2 \times (-1/3) = 0$$

Answer (score 9):

The names *up* and *down* don't refer to *electric* charge $Q$ but are rather  references to [*isospin*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) charge $I_3$.

Answer (score 7):

A neutron consists of three quarks $u d d$(up down down quarks).
The up quark(u) carries charge  $2e/3$ and the down quark(d) carries a charge $ -e/3 $.
Thus $2e/3-e/3-e/3=0$

Answer (score 4):

Because $2/3-1/3-1/3=0                                   $.